# Webdriver is not locating the next datepicker in the screen

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker, webdriver, testng

I am a bit new to automation and i am trying to write a script to fill few data in a particular screen and submit them. Navigation to the screen and adding data to few fields are done properly.

The screen has two datepickers. The **"From date"** one gets picked and date is been posted but not the **"To date"** picker.

[image: Screen view]

Can someone please help me.

This is the code I have developed.

```
public class BusinessCalendar extends Login{

static String Nav = "xxxx";

    @BeforeTest
    public void Navigation(){
        driver.navigate().to(Nav);
    }

    @Test
    public void CreateBusinessCalendar(){
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtBusinessYear")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtBusinessYear")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtBusinessYear")).sendKeys("test year");
        driver.findElement(By.id("dtpFromDates")).clear();   
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[10]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("dtpToDates")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[10]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]")).click();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void CloseBrowser(){
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean `driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[10]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]")).click();` this line is not selecting date from second calendar???

Comment: yes. as well as the .clear(); action on the previous code line is not happening either. as soon as the first datepick action is done the browser freezes and does nothing. Eclipse IDE console doesn't show anything.

Comment: you need to implement some wait before clear second calendar like `Thread.sleep(3000)...`

Comment: Adding the thread.sleep didn't work for me either.

Comment: Do you want to do it using click as in manual testing or you are open to also use jquery/javascript methods?

Comment: What ever the method is fine by me. I just need the data picked @lauda

Comment: if you just need data to be picked, why don't you send value directly to input box of date instead of clicking on datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
@Test
public void CreateBusinessCalendar(){
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtBusinessYear")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtBusinessYear")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtBusinessYear")).sendKeys("test year");
    driver.findElement(By.id("dtpFromDates")).clear();   
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[10]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("dtpToDates")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("dtpToDates")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[10]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]")).click();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No it still didn't work. Thread.sleep required a throws clause so I added that too. But still didn't work for me.

Comment: Are you seeing any exception. If so can you please tell me

Comment: I have swapped the lines 7 and 8 inside the method. Can you please try using this.

Comment: If possible can you please give me the url so that i will try from my end

Comment: The environment is not accessible from outside of the network @k.s. karthik

Comment: Any error you are seeing or just it is not getting selected?

Comment: No any errors are been viewed. The action is not been executed and the browser stays freeze. The console in eclipse also has no any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this script and pass the selector for the date picker.

```
jQuery('datepickerSelector').datepicker( 'setDate', '-1y' );
```

This will select current date last year, you can also use -1d

Comment: It's unclear for me what I should do with the piece of code you have provided. can you please explain? @lauda

Comment: Find a uniques slector for your date picker and execute scripts like:  js.executeScript("my_script");                                                                     In your case js.executeScript("jQuery('datepickerSelector').datepicker( 'setDate', '-1y' );");